# Is it possible in Unity to align the cubemap axes with the camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shader

I'm currently working on 3D insects in Unity, and I want to create a material that mimics the way the mantis or the damselfly eyes behave, especially the little black spot in the middle. For the moment I have a very fine material that makes everything I need, but the reflection cubemap I use for the blackspot is aligned with the world axes by default. Which means that the black spot will only move when I move the object, but in my project only the camera is moving.

Hence my question, is it possible to align the cubemap with the camera's axes, so that when I move the camera, the "front" of the cubemap stays in front of the camera, and so on?

PS: I haven't really messed with shaders yet, so perhaps I just need a line of code or something, please feel free to write it!

Comment: Please add the code you are using for the cube map, shader and scripts.

Comment: @Imapler I created the Cube map with 6 basic textures, and the shader is the default Reflection/Bumped Specular in Unity. I don't use any other script for that material.